# Return promise from action in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i am new in react-redux and for the time been i have a simple page doing login to an existing service(the call is working and i am getting data from the server), i want to get the data in the component and set set cookie and redirect the user based in the data received from the server. 
I am getting the data in the action but in the component it is undefined.
Thank you all

The submit function in the form component:

```
onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.isValid()) {
            this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
            this.props.actions.loginUser(this.state).then(
                function (res) {
                    this.context.router.push('/');
                },
                function (err) {
                    this.setState({ errors: err.response.data.errors, isLoading: false });
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

The action function :

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import loginApi from '../api/loginApi';

export function loginSuccess(result) {
    return { type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, result };
}

export function loginFailed(result) {
    return { type: types.LOGIN_FAILURE, result };
}

export function loginUser(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        return loginApi.loginUser(data).then(result => {
            if (result) {
                if (result.ErrorCode == 0)
                    dispatch(loginSuccess(result));
                else
                    dispatch(loginFailed(result));
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    };
}
```

The api:

```
static loginUser(data) {
   return fetch(API + "/SystemLogin.aspx",
      {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          User: data.identifier,
          Password: data.password
        })
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (parsedData) {
        return parsedData;
        //resolve(parsedData);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error;
      });
  }
```

The reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import LoginApi from '../api/loginApi';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function loginReducer(state = initialState.login, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.courses)];
            //return action.result;
        case types.LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return action.result;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Is there any more code needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is with your reducer code.
It should be like this:-

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import LoginApi from '../api/loginApi';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function loginReducer(state = initialState.login, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, { userProfile: action.results });
            //return action.result;
        case types.LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return action.result;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The second problem is with the way you are trying to send the user to another route.
It should be like this:-

```
onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.isValid()) {
            this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
            this.props.actions.loginUser(this.state);
        }
    }
```

The next problem is inside the render function.Inside render function, put a check for is your 
this.props.userProfile object is defined or not and if it is which will only happen on login success, then redirect him/her to the /homepage route using

`this.context.router.push("/homepage");`

Answer (score 1):

Although the code might be working, it is certainly a hassle to do all the above, the code is not easily comprehensible this way, since you are mixing "dirty" async code within the component and actions.

I advise you to use `redux-saga` to separate the side-effects from the component and actions.

[A good starting point here.](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.md)

step 1: fire an action

step 2: catch the action inside a "saga" instead of a reducer:

```
import { put, takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'

// Our worker Saga: will perform the async increment task
export function* loginUserAsync() {
  yield put({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' })
}

// Our watcher Saga: spawn a new loginUserAsync task on each LOGIN_USER
export function* watchIncrementAsync() {
  yield takeEvery('LOGIN_USER', loginUserAsync)
}
```

step 3: fire a new action after the async code is done and catch it inside a reducer to update state.

step 4: if you have more "dirty" code, simply run it inside the saga (redirection for example)

Comment: He is already using redux thunk I guess. Saga would serve the same purpose

Comment: Hi Ahmad, first thank you for the replay, second is using saga is ok for redux? since i am new to react i am trying to stay in the best practice of writing code. i will read about the saga and try in implement it.

Comment: @Danny sagas are used in redux to solve the "side-effect" problem, and get rid of issues like the ones you are facing, using thunk is good, but it still keeps the "dirty code" mixed in, we've been using sagas in production for a while now and its pretty amazing, its worth trying since youre just starting

Comment: So first think that i would like to accomplish is how not to write this kind of dirty code, and i am reading about saga :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that did you connect the form component with redux ? If yes, you should access the action directly via this.props instead of this.props.actions.loginUser. Maybe this is not the problem because I haven't had a chance to look for the full code of your form component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No sorry that is not the problem